# Rertornar valor Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Tengo este código:

```
function subirArchivos()
{
    var archivos = null;
    var imagen = $("#uploadImage")[0];
    var video = $("#uploadVideo")[0];
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("uploadArchivos[0]", imagen.files[0]);
    formData.append("uploadArchivos[1]", video.files[0]);

     $.ajax({
        url: 'uploadArchivos.php',  
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        xhr: function () {
            xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            $("#cargar").show();
            $("#cargar .progress-bar").attr("aria-valuenow", 0);
            $("#cargar .progress-bar").css("width", "0%");

            xhr.upload.onprogress = function(ev) {
                if (ev.lengthComputable)
                {
                    var percentComplete = parseInt((ev.loaded / ev.total) * 100);
                    $("#cargar .progress-bar").attr("aria-valuenow", percentComplete);
                    $("#cargar .progress-bar").css("width", percentComplete + "%");

                    if(percentComplete == 100)
                    {
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            $("#cargar").hide();        
                        }, 2000);
                    }
                }
            }

            return xhr;
        },
        success: function(data){
            if(data != "error")
                archivos = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            else
                $("#error-subir").show();
        }
    });

    return archivos;
}
```

La función `subirArchivos()` como pueden ver se encarga de subir archivos al servidor por medio de una petición ajax, ahora cuando recibo respuesta del servidor en la función que se invoca en el success, si la respuesta es diferente a error lo que hago es parsear el JSON que se esta recibiendo y posteriormente lo guardo en la variable `archivos` ya que esta es la que pretendo que retorne como valor la función `subirArchivos()`.

```
function insertarPelicula()
{   
    var formulario = $("#form-registro");

    var titulo = $("#tituloVal").val();
    var clasificacion = $("#clasificacionVal").val();
    var genero = $("#generoVal").val();
    var duracion = $("#duracionVal").val();
    var pais = $("#paisVal").val();
    var ano = $("#anoVal").val();
    var sinopsis = $("#sinopsisVal").val();
    var actores = $("#actoresVal").val();
    var directores = $("#directoresVal").val();

    if(formulario.valid())
    {
        var archivos = subirArchivos();

        if(archivos == null)
            return false;

        $.ajax({
            url: "insert.php",
            data: "titulo=" + titulo + "&clasificacion=" + clasificacion + "&genero=" + genero + "&duracion=" + duracion
                  + "&pais=" + pais + "&ano=" + ano + "&sinopsis=" + sinopsis + "&actores=" + actores
                  + "&directores=" + directores + "&archivos=" + JSON.stringify(archivos),
            type: "POST",
            success: function(data){
                if(data == 1)
                {
                    $("#correcto").fadeIn(3000);
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        window.location.reload(true);
                    }, 2000);
                }
                else
                    $("#error").fadeIn(3000);
            }
        }); 
    }
}
```

La función `insertarPelicula()` es la que invoca a la función `subirArchivos()` que devuelve un valor. El problema aquí es que no consigo que la función `subirArchivos()` me devuelva el JSON que se obtiene al subir los archivos, me devuelve puro null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema es un clásico: esperar un comportamiento **síncrono** de un código **asíncrono**.

Vamos a dividir tu función `subirArchivos( )` es 2 partes: lo que se ejecuta síncrono (de principio a fín), y lo asíncrono.

```
function subirArchivos()
{
    var archivos = null;
    var imagen = $("#uploadImage")[0];
    var video = $("#uploadVideo")[0];
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("uploadArchivos[0]", imagen.files[0]);
    formData.append("uploadArchivos[1]", video.files[0]);

    CÓDIGO ASÍNCRONO

    return archivos;
}
```

Aunque parezca que no, tu código se ejecuta **exactamente como he mostrado**. Todo el código síncrono se ejecuta **de principio a fin**. La parte asíncrona queda *a la espera* de poder ejecutarse: en tu caso, a la espera de la respuesta AJAX.

Queda claramente visible tu problema: tu variable `archivos` se retorna con el último valor asignado ... en tu caso, `null`.

La solución es la habitual en estos casos: **no esperar un valor de retorno** desde un código asíncrono, sino **invocar** desde el código asíncrono aquello que requiera dicho valor:

```
function insertarPelicula( ) {
  var formulario = $( "#form-registro" );
  var titulo = $( "#tituloVal" ).val( );
  var clasificacion = $( "#clasificacionVal" ).val( );
  var genero = $( "#generoVal" ).val( );
  var duracion = $( "#duracionVal" ).val( );
  var pais = $( "#paisVal" ).val( );
  var ano = $( "#anoVal" ).val( );
  var sinopsis = $( "#sinopsisVal" ).val( );
  var actores = $( "#actoresVal" ).val( );
  var directores = $( "#directoresVal" ).val( );

  if( formulario.valid( ) ) { subirArchivos( insertarRealmentePelicula ); }

  function insertarRealmentePelicula( archivos ) {
    if( archivos === null ) return;

    $.ajax( {
      url: "insert.php",
      data: "titulo=" + titulo + "&clasificacion=" + clasificacion + "&genero=" + genero + "&duracion=" + duracion + "&pais=" + pais + "&ano=" + ano + "&sinopsis=" + sinopsis + "&actores=" + actores + "&directores=" + directores + "&archivos=" + JSON.stringify( archivos ),
      type: "POST",
      success: function( data ){
        if( data == 1 ) {
          $( "#correcto" ).fadeIn( 3000 );
          setTimeout( function( ) {
            window.location.reload( true );
          }, 2000 );
        } else $( "#error" ).fadeIn( 3000 );
      }
    } );
  }

  function subirArchivos( cb ) {
    var archivos = null;
    var imagen = $( "#uploadImage" )[0];
    var video = $( "#uploadVideo" )[0];
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append( "uploadArchivos[0]", imagen.files[0] );
    formData.append( "uploadArchivos[1]", video.files[0] );

    $.ajax( {
      url: 'uploadArchivos.php',  
      type: 'POST',
      data: formData,
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      xhr: function( ) {
        xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr( );
        $( "#cargar" ).show( );
        $( "#cargar .progress-bar" ).attr( "aria-valuenow", 0 );
        $( "#cargar .progress-bar" ).css( "width", "0%" );

        xhr.upload.onprogress = function( ev ) {
          if( ev.lengthComputable ) {
            var percentComplete = parseInt( ( ev.loaded / ev.total ) * 100 );

            $( "#cargar .progress-bar" ).attr( "aria-valuenow", percentComplete );
            $( "#cargar .progress-bar" ).css( "width", percentComplete + "%" );

            if( percentComplete == 100 ) {
              setTimeout( function( ){
                $("#cargar").hide( );
              }, 2000 );
            }
          }
        }

        return xhr;
      },
      success: function( data ) {
        if( data != "error" ) {
          archivos = jQuery.parseJSON( data );
          cb( archivos );
        } else
          $( "#error-subir" ).show( );
      }
    } );
  }
}
```